# Box API Irregular Headers

Tags: node.js, http, box-api

I am trying to upload an image with the box API and the [`request module`](https://github.com/mikeal/request). I tried the provided curl example without any problems.

I have a request all setup like this

```
var request = require("request");
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

request({
    url: "https://api.box.com/2.0/files/content",
    method: "POST",
    form: {
        filename: fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, "midguts.jpg")),
        folder_id: "0"
    },
    headers: {
        api_key: "<API_KEY>",
        auth_token: "<AUTH_TOKEN>"
    }
}, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(body);
});
```

The problem arises when I get to the headers part. The [`box API`](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file) call for a headers string of

```
"Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN"
```

but I with the request module I can only send an object of key, value pairs. I also looked at the docs for nodes [`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) and found it has the same issue.

So the question is, why does the API not follow the standard key pair format and how can I send a POST request that will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Authorization` is the name of the HTTP Header ([see also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)).  This might work better:

```
headers: {
    Authorization: "BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a little confusing.

Comment: I agree. It initially confused me because the authorization type (e.g. Basic, BoxAuth) is a standalone argument of the header, but I mistook it for the key of the key/value pair.